# cannot load CUDAFunction from cubin, ptx or library file

Tags: cudalink

According to the documentation of `CUDAFunctionLoad` it should be easy to specify a compiled file (cubin, ptx, dll should all work) as the source for loading a `CUDAFunction`. Unfortunately it does not for me. Compiling from source works fine, but as soon as I try to load the `CUDAFunction` from the compiled file (I tried cubin, ptx and a dll) things fail.

Here is a very simple example that does not work for me, no matter what combination I try (you can just copy and paste the code into mathematica and run it as long as you have a proper CUDA setup):

Let's create a cubin file first from a very simple CUDA kernel:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"];
code = "
  __global__ void addTwo(int * in, int * out, int length) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (index < length)
        out[index] = in[index] + 2;
  }";
cubinFile = CreateExecutable[code, "test", "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler, 
   "CreateCUBIN" -> True];
```

This successfully creates `test.cubin`.

Unfortunately loading the function `addTwo` fails:

```
cudaFun = CUDAFunctionLoad[File[cubinFile], 
   "addTwo", {{"Integer32", _, "Input"}, {"Integer32", _, 
     "Output"}, "Integer32"}, 256, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, 
   "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print];
```

> CUDAFunctionLoad::invsrc: CUDALink encountered invalid source input. The source input must be either a string containing the program, or a list of one element indicating the file containing the program.

The input file should be valid, but maybe I am missing something obvious here. Interestingly enough going the same route creating a `.ptx` file yields a different error:

```
ptxFile = 
  CreateExecutable[code, "test", "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler, 
   "CreatePTX" -> True];
cudaFun = 
  CUDAFunctionLoad[File[ptxFile], 
   "addTwo", {{"Integer32", _, "Input"}, {"Integer32", _, 
     "Output"}, "Integer32"}, 256, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, 
   "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print];
```

> CUDAFunctionLoad::notfnd: CUDALink resource not found.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here and how I can actually load a `CUDAFunction` from a compiled file?

You can just copy and paste the code above into mathematica and run it as long as you have CUDA setup properly. Can you reproduce the behavior?

---

Additional Information:
I am running Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10.
Latest CUDA Paclet installed. CUDA setup working fine (can load CUDAFunctions from source, compile files, etc.).

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the filename by braces (`{}`)? The first error message ask for a _list_ containing a single element, namely the filename. Admittedly, that's rather unconventional in Mathematica but this can shield a string containing the filename from interpretation as a code string...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Yes, I did. Same error message.

Comment: Okay, that was just a shot into the dark for me. My graphics card not supporting CUDA, I cannot help you any further... Sorry.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I get your reasoning and I had the same thought when reading the error message. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: The error message is misleading. It appears because a function fails in a very deep level of the code. The error is handled using `Throw[$Failed]` which is then caught by the part that creates the misleading error. The real error in the first case can be examined by evaluating the `CUDAFunctionLoad` line, then calling ``<<LibraryLink` ``, and then evaluating `$LibraryError`. For me this gives ".../libCUDALink_Double.so: undefined symbol: WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper". I spend a good 2 h debugging the CUDALink package and when I hear back from support@wri, I give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @halirutan: You are one of the heroes of these forums! Thank you so much for all your efforts. I am truly amazed by your commitment and dedication to the community.

Comment: "Our engineer most familiar with CUDA programming is out for the week. He will be most likely to provide assistance on this issue. I have asked that he look at this as soon as he returns. I apologize for the delay here, but if there is a potential solution/workaround for what you're seeing he will be most likely to find it." I guess the answer will arrive too late to grab your bounty and my findings will only tell you why it doesn't work and why I believe it is a bug.

Comment: @hailrutan: Thank you very much for the follow up. I would appreciate if you would leave more information here, if you hear back from Wolfram support once again. I would say there is at least hope that this issue gets fixed in a future mathematica update. I also do hope they put more emphasis on cuda development for their future releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go: Upfront, this was a pain as the `` CUDALink` `` package uses `` GPUTools` ``, `` LibraryLink` `` and since we are compiling on our own, `` CCompilerDriver` `` played its own role. Therefore, it was a lot of code to look at but I believe I found the reason.

**TL;DR** Okay, okay... I believe the main mistake was that by compiling the code with `CreateExecutable` does [name-mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) which prevented Mathematica from successfully using the compiled kernel. Therefore, a minimal working example on my machine is the following:

```
<< CUDALink`

code = "
  __global__ void addTwo(int * in, int * out, int length) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (index < length)
        out[index] = in[index] + 2;
  }";
cubin = CreateExecutable[code,
  "AddTwo",
  "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler,
  "CUDAArchitecture" -> {"sm_61"},
  "CreateBinary" -> True,
  "CreateCUBIN" -> True,
  "UnmangleCode" -> True]
CUDAFunctionLoad[File[cubin], "addTwo", {{"Integer32", _, "Input"},
  {"Integer32", _, "Output"}, "Integer32"}, 256]
```

### Steps to investigate

First, I needed to find out where on earth this error was coming from. I was stepwise following the code and in my case, the problem was in

```
CUDALink`Private`SetKernel["addTwo"]
```

If you look closer, then this calls a function

```
CUDALink`Private`cSetKernel["Double"]["addTwo"]
```

that returned a

```
LibraryFunctionError["LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR", 6]
```

On the other hand, if you used `CUDAFunctionLoad[code, ...]` this call succeeded. This was hard to find, because above function simply `Throw[$Failed]` and the returned message what this exception was caught was not very helpful.

Now I started tracing back why this was failing. For this I mainly used `PrintDefinitions` from the `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` package because it lets me instantly change the code of the built-in functions and I could throw in some `Print` calls.

I knew that the `CUDAFunctionLoad` had to compile the kernel when it only gets code. When you look at the `InputForm` of a `CUDAFunction` you see the compiler switches it uses. I copied this exactly but still no luck. Then I got the idea to look at the md5 sum of the created `cubin` files: The one I create and the one that was automatically created by `CUDAFunctionLoad`. This was as different as their sizes were. That was odd.

After having a nice dinner and letting this settle for a bit, it hit me: How on earth can I be sure that the compiler call is the only thing that has to match. There must be a place where `CUDAFunctionLoad` calls itself `CreateExectuable`.

### Solution

If my above example does not work for you, but you can successfully use `CUDAFunctionLoad` to compile a CUDA Kernel, or if you are just curious, then  open the code for `` CUDALink`Private`iCompileCUDAKernel `` like this

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[CUDALink`Private`iCompileCUDAKernel]
```

Near the end of the first long definition, you will find a Block:

```
Block[{CCompilerDriver`$ErrorMessageHead = errMsgHd},
        fileName = Check[
                Quiet[
                    CCompilerDriver`CreateExecutable[prog, fileName, Sequence@@createLibraryOpts],
                    CUDALink`Private`errMsgHd::wddirty
                ],
                $Failed
            ]
    ];
```

Before the call to `CreateExecutable`, just throw in a

```
Print[{prog, fileName, Sequence @@ createLibraryOpts}]
```

You need to do this on a fresh kernel when you have already compiled your CUDA kernel with `CUDAFunctionLoad` because things are cached. Evaluate the cell with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then call

```
CUDAFunctionLoad[code, ...]
```

You will see the exact arguments to `CreateExecutable` that `CUDALink` uses internally. There are a lot more that I have given above, but the rest weren't necesarry in my case. If you compile your kernel with these options, you should be able to load the `cubin`.

I will send the support@WRI this information and ask them if they also feel that this should be documented somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I tried your solution and it works. Interestingly enough I really had to manually specify `"CUDAArchitecture" -> {"sm_61"}`, as you did in your example above (it happens to conform to my Geforce GTX 1070).